# How to approach abstract art image AI captioning

Tags: ai-design

I tried `sachin/vit2distilgpt2` to caption an abstract image I have, and it seemed to output a blank string for the caption. I'm new to this, but my goal is to caption some of my abstract artwork - for instance describe the colors, sharpness, vividness, what it may be representing or abstractly looks like.

What could I use to approach setting up and/or training an AI model to characterize and caption abstract artwork?

Comment: To get a sense of the possibilities you can use the "describe" command in midjourney

Comment: Check out the "Image to Text" section: https://pharmapsychotic.com/tools.html for clip interrogation techniques.